# Node Express serving dynamic and static files with a single page application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mime-types

I'm building a single page application and using node (v7.7.1) for server and express for routing and building the API.

My frontend is packaged into a folder called `/client` (so all you JS, css, img and html are there). And my API has for root url `/api`.

Any other queries that are not files or API should be sent the `index.html`. So I tried the following:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client')));
app.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.originalUrl.indexOf('/api') !== -1) {
        return next()
    }
    if (/\/(\w|-)+\.\w{2,5}$/gmi.test(req.originalUrl)) {
            return res.sendFile(rss);
    }
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.html')); 
});
```

The above is giving me errors for `mime` type error in console for css and js files (maybe images as well, but can't tell since nothing loads).

Browser console:

```
Refused to apply style from '/app-2432393bf1588983d4f6.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Any tips on how to do this better or how to fix issue much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something more like :

```
app.use(express.static(path.normalize(__dirname, '../client'))); // This will serve index.html by default on the "/" route

app.get('/api/:func', (req, res, next) => { // Call this with "/api/save"
        console.log(`Called the API's ${req.params.func} function`);
        next()
    })
    .get("/file/:filename", (req,res) => res.sendFile(req.params.filename) ) // call "/file/style.css"
```

**EDIT** after OP's comments

> 1) What about sending all other traffic to index.html ? My frontend
>   handles any page not founds and the sorts.

You can do a redirection

```
app.get( "*", (req,res) => res.redirect("/") )
```

> 2) I had this before but then then for some reason that doesn't make
>   sense to me, when I looked at the source of the file found for
>   style.css it was my html page.

Uh, not sure how to check or debug that...

Comment: Thanks. 1) What about sending all other traffic to index.html ? My frontend handles any page not founds and the sorts. 2) I had this before but then then for some reason that doesn't make sense to me, when I looked at the source of the file found for `style.css` it was my html page.

Answer (score 1):

do it like this way

```
   function getRoutes(){
      const router = require('express').Router();
      router.get('/abc',function(req,res,next){
         //logic
      })
      router.post('/bcd',function(req,res,next){
        //logic
      })
      router.all('*',function(req,res,next){
         res.redirect('/');   
      })   //make sure this one is always at the last of all routes. 
      return router;
   }     
app.use('/',express.static(__dirname +'/client'))); // for static content
app.use('/api',getRoutes());
```

it can be handled in many more ways.

let me know if it helps you

Comment: ...but what exactly is `yourAPIRouting`?

Comment: any express middleware which returns `Router` function where other routes can be defined  @JeremyThille

Comment: @SaikatHajra Thanks. What about sending any other path the html file since it's a single page?

Comment: Like my index.html handles the 404 states and `/home`, `/about`, `/...`

Comment: if you add more content in your question it will helpful to answer you

Comment: I'm using `React` on the frontend which handles all the routing, hence the `Single Page Application`.